# try to put a image with transparency on a plane (three.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new with three.js and I want show a image ( png image with transparency ) on a plane but my code don't work...

this is my code:

```js
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'images/lampedepoche.png' );
    
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(300, 80);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: texture, color: 0xFFFFFF});
material.emissive.set(0x333333);
material.shininess = 60;
    
var ldp = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(ldp);
```

this is my image:

[image: lampe de poche]

and this is all my code:

```js
window.onload = init();


function init(){
    // on initialise le moteur de rendu
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    
    // on initialise la scène
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    // on initialise la camera que l’on place ensuite sur la scène
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000 );
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);
    scene.add(camera);
    
    // plane
 me = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(900,550), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff}));
 scene.add( me );
    
    me.position.x = 130;
    me.position.y = 10;
    me.rotation.y = -20;
    
    var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'images/lampedepoche.png' );
    
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(300, 80);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: texture, color: 0xFFFFFF});  
    material.transparent = true
    var ldp = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(ldp);
    
    ldp.position.x = -410;
    document.getElementById("positionlx").value = 0;
    
    // on créé un  cube au quel on définie un matériau puis on l’ajoute à la scène 
    cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 100, 100, 100 ), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:0x00ffff}) );
    scene.add( cube );
    
    
    cube.position.y = 0;
    cube.position.x = 0;
    cube.position.z = 0;
    cube.rotation.y = 0;
    
    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x212223) );
      
    light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1);
    light.position.set(-320,0,0);
    light.angle = Math.PI/5;
    light.shadowCameraVisible = true;
    scene.add(light);
    
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapDarkness = 1;
    
     light.castShadow = true;
     light.intensity = 0.8;
     cube.castShadow = true;
     cube.receiveShadow = true;
     me.receiveShadow = true;
    
     lightHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper( light );
     scene.add(lightHelper);
    
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

May be I did some mistake ... like I am beginner in javascript

I need help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried material.transparent = true ?

Comment: Your code and texture image, including the transparency, seem to work fine when I plug it into my own scene and set material.transparent=true. What exactly isn't working ... are you seeing the image without the transparency, or seeing nothing at all?

Comment: I am seeing nothing at all

Comment: You're rendering the scene immediately after constructing it, but rendering it only once. The texture hasn't loaded by the time the scene is rendered, so you won't see it appear until after the scene has been rendered again. You either A) need to wait until the texture has loaded before rendering the scene, or B) add an animation loop or some other update to cause the scene to re-render periodically. Try adding as crude test: setTimeout(function(){renderer.render( scene, camera )}, 1000);

Comment: Another crude test: change the texture loader to THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'images/lampedepoche.png', function(){renderer.render(scene, camera)} ); (render the scene after the texture has loaded.)